# How to use groupby in mongo along with addFields containing strings?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have four fields `Sender`, `Recipient`, `Credit`, `Debit` in mongo collection. Of which Credit and Debit are numbers in form of strings. I need to group based on `Sender`, `Recipient` and add integer values of `Credit`, `Debit` and sort the result based on that net value of credit and debit

I have database like this

```
Sender   Recipient  Credit  Debit
“Mike”   “John”      “600”   “-300” 
“Alis”   “Ajay”      “300”   “-800” 
“Arun”   “Ankit”     “360”   “-300” 
“Mike”    “Cris”      “0”    “-100”
```

And I need result like this

```
Sender   Recipient  NetAmount
“Mike”    “John”        “300” 
Arun”     “Ankit”       “-60”
“Mike”    “Cris”        “-100”       
“Alis”    “Ajay”        “-500”
```

I tried to do this

```
DataModel.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            sender: '$ sender,
            recipient: '$recipient',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          credit: '$credit.creditAmount,
          debit: '$debit.debitAmount,
        },
      }, {
        $addFields: {
          netAmount: {
            $add: [{ $toInt: '$ credit }, { $toInt: '$ debit }],
          },
        }
      },
    ]);
```

But it didn't give the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `Sender` and `Recipient`, sum `Credit` and `Debit` amount after converting to integer using `$toInt`
- `$project` to show required fields and sum `Credit` and `Debit` field using `$add`
- `$match` to check `NetAmount` is not zero
- `$sort` by `NetAmount` in descending order

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        Sender: "$Sender",
        Recipient: "$Recipient"
      },
      Credit: { $sum: { $toInt: "$Credit" } },
      Debit: { $sum: { $toInt: "$Debit" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Sender: "$_id.Sender",
      Recipient: "$_id.Recipient",
      NetAmount: { $add: ["$Credit", "$Debit"] }
    }
  },
  { $match: { NetAmount: { $ne: 0 } } },
  { $sort: { NetAmount: -1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M6PYAGASDG9)

Comment: Could you please help to extend it with one more condition:

After grouping, I need to filter out the records where the NetAmount is not equal to zero

Comment: Thanks and it will be grateful if you could solve another doubt. After sorting and match, i need to get top 3 records of each group. Could you please help with that too

Comment: it would be good if you ask new question with details.

Comment: as you said, i have updated it as new question, please help with this. Here is the link for the question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738919